# Sample of a random variable and the corresponding distribution

Tags: statistics

I am trying to understand, rather comprehend how can one talk about a probability distribution, when considering a sample of values, that a random variable can take.

I don't understand how can one look at some values and say that, we are dealing with a normal probability distribution. First of all, how is it possible that a variable, which ultimately is characterized by a continuous probability distribution such as the normal distribution, how can such a continuous variable have a finite-single value? Last time I checked, we cannot talk about the single value that a variable with continuous probability distribution can take, because that is zero. Instead we talk about a value of the random variable that falls into a range of values, with a certain probability. So how exactly can a random variable, with a normal distribution, have a single value?

The set up would be:

We have two samples of random values, that 2 different random variables can take. We consider two individuals, one that knows the probability distributions of the two variables, where one follows a Poisson distribution (a discrete probability distribution) and the other a normal distribution. The other individual has no idea and needs to find the respective probability distributions of the two random variables. How can he tell? How is it possible for a random variable that is characterized by a continuous probability distribution to take a single value and not be defined as taking values from a certain range? I don't understand.

Or another example:  uniform samples. How can one tell that the random variable, that can take any of the values in the sample, has a uniform distribution?

Comment: Without any further information, a distribution (discrete or continuous) cannot be inferred from such a small sample.

Comment: What other information can you have, other then a sample of values, a large one?

Comment: Larger sample plus some information about data source.  For a large enough sample graph would help.